How can I implement Google OAuth in my Next.js app without using any npm package like @react-oauth/google
I’m trying to implement Google OAuth in my Next.js 14 application without relying on any third-party npm packages like @react-oauth/google. I want to manage the OAuth flow manually, including loading the Google API script, displaying the Google Sign-In button, and handling the authentication process.
but according to my current implemention google pop up appear after signing in with google i should be redirected but pop up close and nothing happend
Please help me
in my main layout file
import type { Metadata } from "next"
import { Urbanist } from "next/font/google"
import "./globals.css"
import Script from "next/script"

const urbanist = Urbanist({ subsets: ["latin"] })

export const metadata: Metadata = {
    title: "Create Next App",
    description: "Generated by create next app"
}

export default function RootLayout({
    children
}: Readonly<{
    children: React.ReactNode
}>) {
    return (
        <html lang="en">
            <head>
            <Script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></Script>
         <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="YOUR_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com">
            </head>
            <body className={urbanist.className}>{children}</body>
        </html>
    )
}

and my component contains this div which is responsible to show google button which open popup
<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
